# Is electron interference because of energy transformation from wave to particle and vice versa?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, interference

I read about electron interference that in presence of photons there are no fringes formed but in its absence fringe patterns are formed. 
Can it be explained like this. An electron travels free as a wave . In absence of photons since they are waves they produce interference pattern. But in presence of photons electron wave transforms to particle so there is no wave pattern observed. 
Is this Correct?
Or if there is some other possible explanation for this phenomena then please explain.

Comment: I think you should give a link on your "I read". There is  confusion in what you are asking which cannot be resolved unless one knows what you are quoting.

Comment: A quantum object is **neither** a wave nor a particle, though it carries properties of both. Unless you explain a bit more what you are asking about, this question remains unclear

Comment: @ACuriousMind , I think that it is clear. The user heard something non-clear as she/he asks us what's that.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the wave nature of elementary particles exists in the probability distributions that describe them, which are predicted by the square of the wavefunction that is the solution for the specific boundary conditions.

Comment: @anna-v Feynman, for example, says that when electrons are passed through two slits the  registration of the interference pattern depends on whether one observes which slit the electron passes through. The observation is done by scattering photons off the electrons after they have passed through the slits.

Comment: There have been experiments since then that show clearly that it is the change in the boundary conditions that destroys interference. A secondary interaction as you describe will break the coherence with he original beam. The interference pattern is a probability distribution, as clearly can be seen in the accumulation of single photon or single electron at the time.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles . see the next paragraph also "which way"

Comment: For the single electron the coherence is in the quantum mechancical wave function "electron two slits scatter", which will have a phase which will give the probability ( wavefunction squared) to find the electron on the (x,y) of the screen. The problem "electron +twoslits+photon scatter" is a different problem,with different probability distributions and the accumulation of data which measures the probability distribution will lose the phase coherence imposed by the two slits only in the boundary conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of inexact things here:

**1)** "electrons travel free as a wave".

Yes, for our mathematical treatment sometimes it is convenient to treat the traveling electron as a wave. But if the traveling electron is really a wave **in the nature**, on this there is a debate of tens of years.

**2)** "in absence of photons, since they are waves, ..."

If the above description as waves is good for the treatment of the respective experiment, it remains good also if photons **yes** are present around, however the electron wave is **perturbed**.

**3)** "in presence of photons electron wave transforms to particle so there is no wave pattern observed.

The formulation "in presence of photons" isn't good. Photons may be present, but not allowed to influence the electrons. Putting it simply, if we try to "watch" the electrons by means of light or whatever other particles that cross the path of the electrons and interact somehow with them, the pattern may be gone.

As an explanation, for producing an interference pattern we split the electron beam by means, for instance, of a 2slit configuration. Well, if photons, or other particles illuminate at least one of the two beams, the interference pattern will be gone.

One of the causes for which the illumination of the electrons during their travel destroys the pattern, is called "decoherence". This is a drastic disturbation of the phases of the two beams due to interaction of the beams with macroscopic apparatuses or with a huge an uncontrollable number of other particles (e.g. your photons). In this case we won't see anymore fringes. Another cause is simply *entanglement with other particles* e.g. a few photons. In the latter case a state of a couple of particles appears, one of the particles being the electron, other particle(s) the photon(s). The phases of the two electron beams are "complicated" with the additional particles, s.t. on the photographic plate again we won't get fringes.

Comment: So you mean to say that electron is not a wave and not a particle at one instant. Always it is a mixture. But there is dominance of one character over the other in the above situation. And this explains the phenomena.

Comment: Also it is the change in phase because of  entanglement of electrons with photons that dismisses the pattern

Comment: @user70848 , yeas, I am with you. No, I don't mean that the electron is not a wave. I will explain in continuation.

Comment: @user70848 : we don't know what exactly we have in our apparatuses. There is a debate of tens of years. Sometimes it is more convenient to represent the traveling electron as a wave. Also in the atom we treat it as a wave, but the wave in the atom poses us **very** difficult problems. Not that a "particle picture" would be better, no, it would be worse.

Comment: The "particle picture" is sometimes convenient. In experiments with high-energy electrons and that pass through ion chambers, the "wave-picture" may be futile. Why? Because the wave-packet of the electron is so small that we can say that we have a particle. But I have to tell you more.

Comment: The particle picture *imposes itself on us* at the moment when the electron delivers its energy to the photographic plate. The wave-packet has quite a big transversal section, it illuminates all the fringe region. And though, the energy is delivered to one molecule in the photographic plate. In all, we get on the plate a small dark spot. Then we say, *it's a particle because it leaves on the plate a single spot". So, we leave with a dilemma: if it is a particle, why do we get interference? If it is a wave, why it impresses the plate only in a tiny place?